# Application context loading failed in tests when I drop mongodb collection on spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I have a java 17 - spring boot maven application with mongodb.
I want to drop my collection, when I start the app local, everthing works fine but if I want to create a docker-image, the contextLoads() test is failed because of  "IllegalState Failed to load Application context".

This is my configuration to delete the collection

```
package com.jiraRestApi.datajiramongodb;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private JiraIssueRepository jiraIssueRepository;

    protected  DataLoader(JiraIssueRepository jiraIssueRepository){
        this.jiraIssueRepository = jiraIssueRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.jiraIssueRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

```
package com.jiraRestApi.datajiramongodb;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DataJiraMongodbApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataJiraMongodbApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

the auto generated test

```
package com.jiraRestApi.datajiramongodb;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
@SpringBootTest
class DataJiraMongodbApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: Jira-issues
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
```

I already tried: mongoOperations.dropCollection(.class) but got the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please share the complete stack-trace of the error, this will be helpful for investigation.

From the error text that you provided "IllegalState Failed to load Application context" the issue could be that the bean configured in your project might have faced some error in creation upon execution of the test case.

I can see you have a component class `DataLoader` in you code. It could be that this component could not be properly created due to missing configuration (i cannot confirm this since the stack trace is not available). It could be that you might need to configure an applciation.yaml for the test case also, say application-test.yaml.

You can also refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-junit-failed-to-load-applicationcontext for more idea related to @SpringBootTest applicationContext here. Hope this helps.